# How can Akka streams be materialized continually?

Tags: scala, akka, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk, akka-stream

I am using [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-index.html) in Scala to poll from an [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) queue using the [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/). I created an [ActorPublisher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-integrations.html#ActorPublisher) which dequeues messages on a two second interval:

```
class SQSSubscriber(name: String) extends ActorPublisher[Message] {
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val schedule = context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 2 seconds, self, "dequeue")

  val client = new AmazonSQSClient()
  client.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion("us-east-1"))
  val url = client.getQueueUrl(name).getQueueUrl

  val MaxBufferSize = 100
  var buf = Vector.empty[Message]

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "dequeue" =>
      val messages = iterableAsScalaIterable(client.receiveMessage(new ReceiveMessageRequest(url).getMessages).toList
      messages.foreach(self ! _)
    case message: Message if buf.size == MaxBufferSize =>
      log.error("The buffer is full")
    case message: Message =>
      if (buf.isEmpty && totalDemand > 0)
        onNext(message)
      else {
        buf :+= message
        deliverBuf()
      }
    case Request(_) =>
      deliverBuf()
    case Cancel =>
      context.stop(self)
  }

  @tailrec final def deliverBuf(): Unit =
    if (totalDemand > 0) {
      if (totalDemand <= Int.MaxValue) {
        val (use, keep) = buf.splitAt(totalDemand.toInt)
        buf = keep
        use foreach onNext
      } else {
        val (use, keep) = buf.splitAt(Int.MaxValue)
        buf = keep
        use foreach onNext
        deliverBuf()
      }
    }
}
```

In my application, I am attempting to run the flow at a 2 second interval as well:

```
val system = ActorSystem("system")
val sqsSource = Source.actorPublisher[Message](SQSSubscriber.props("queue-name"))
val flow = Flow[Message]
  .map { elem => system.log.debug(s"${elem.getBody} (${elem.getMessageId})"); elem }
  .to(Sink.ignore)

system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 2 seconds) {
  flow.runWith(sqsSource)(ActorMaterializer()(system))
}
```

However, when I run my application I receive `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [20000 milliseconds]` and subsequent dead letter notices which is caused by the `ActorMaterializer`.

Is there a recommended approach for continually materializing an Akka Stream?

Comment: I'm not able to test it now, but I'm not sure about using more than one instances of ActorMaterializer. You are using one instance inside ActorPublisher and another one for entire flow.

Comment: I ended up using Akka-Camel since it has a nice SQS integration which accomplished all that I needed to do (https://github.com/fzakaria/Akka-Camel-SQS/).

Comment: Is there a reason you have to continuously use a different ActorPublisher every 2 seconds?  Based on the sample code given it would be much easier to just keep using the same publisher...

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you need to create a new `ActorPublisher` every 2 seconds.  This seems redundant and wasteful of memory.  Also, I don't think an ActorPublisher is necessary.  From what I can tell of the code, your implementation will have an ever growing number of Streams all querying the same data.  Each `Message` from the client will be processed by N different akka Streams and, even worse, N will grow over time.

**Iterator For Infinite Loop Querying**

You can get the same behavior from your ActorPublisher by using scala's `Iterator`.  It is possible to create an Iterator which continuously queries the client:

```
//setup the client
val client = {
  val sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient()
  sqsClient setRegion (RegionUtils getRegion "us-east-1")
  sqsClient
}

val url = client.getQueueUrl(name).getQueueUrl

//single query
def queryClientForMessages : Iterable[Message] = iterableAsScalaIterable {
  client receiveMessage (new ReceiveMessageRequest(url).getMessages)
}

def messageListIteartor : Iterator[Iterable[Message]] = 
  Iterator continually messageListStream

//messages one-at-a-time "on demand", no timer pushing you around
def messageIterator() : Iterator[Message] = messageListIterator flatMap identity
```

This implementation only queries the client when all previous Messages have been consumed and is therefore truly [reactive](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/).  No need to keep track of a buffer with fixed size.  Your solution needs a buffer because the creation of Messages (via a timer) is de-coupled from the consumption of Messages (via println).  In my implementation, creation & consumption are [tightly coupled](https://www.google.com/search?q=kermit%20ms%20piggy%20wedding%20images) via back-pressure.

**Akka Stream Source**

You can then use this Iterator generator-function to feed an akka stream Source:

```
def messageSource : Source[Message, _] = Source fromIterator messageIterator
```

**Flow Formation**

And finally you can use this Source to perform the `println` (As a side note: your `flow` value is actually a `Sink` since `Flow + Sink = Sink`).  Using your `flow` value from the question:

```
messageSource runWith flow
```

One akka Stream processing all messages.