# Akka Streams: missing last element in Source

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32544467/1332556)
to create an SQS consumer using Akka Streams:

```
  def queryForMessages = {
    val messages = Sqs.receive(queueUrl, 3, 10)
    println(s"Received from sqs: ${messages.map(_.getBody)}")
    messages
  }

  def messageListStream : immutable.Stream[Iterable[SqsMessage]] = {
    queryForMessages #:: messageListStream
  }

  def messageIterator() : Iterator[SqsMessage] = messageListStream.flatten.toIterator

  Source.fromIterator(messageIterator)
    .map(_.getBody)
    .runForeach(m => println(s"Stream output: $m"))(materializer)
```

It all seems to work, apart from the fact that the last element that was received from the queue does not get picked up by the stream. 
ie if I post four items to sqs, only 3 of them get printed out at by the stream (item "2" is missing). The output I get is:

```
Received from sqs: List(1)
Received from sqs: List(3, 4, 2)
Stream output: 1
Stream output: 3
Stream output: 4
Received from sqs: List()
Received from sqs: List()
```

The missing element (2) does actually appear though if I post some more elements:

```
Received from sqs: List(5)
Stream output: 2
Received from sqs: List(6)
Stream output: 5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I gave the answer you referenced in your question.  I suspect the problem arises from the lazy nature of evaluating a stream tail.  Try this instead: `def messageIterator() = Iterator.continually(messageListStream).flatMap(identity)`

Comment: `Iterator.continually(queryForMessages).flatMap(identity)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments section I believe the source of the problem is the fact that Streams, and therefore lazy tail evaluation, are being used as an intermediary.

The Stream component is unnecessary because an `Iterator` alone can solve the problem:

```
val messageListIterator : () => Iterator[Iterable[SqsMessage]] = 
  () => Iterator continually queryForMessages

val messageIterator : () => Iterator[SqsMessage] = 
  () => messageListIterator() flatMap identity
```

This can now be used in your akka stream `Source`:

```
Source
  .fromIterator(messageIterator)
  .map(_.getBody)
  .runForeach(m => println(s"Stream output: $m"))(materializer)
```

I have updated [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544467/how-can-akka-streams-be-materialized-continually) accordingly.